# Join based on the value to different table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi everyone I have a table `TableC` which saves primary key values from two different tables `TableA` and `TableB`. because they are primary keys from two tables I could have end up with duplicates in that `tableC` so when Storing values I prefixed the Primary keys with a short text to differentiate that which value is coming from which table.

Now I would like to Join this `tableC` with `TableA` and `TableB` to get the data from `tableA` and `TableB`

```
TableC : 

ID_Column 
1A
1B
2A

TableA: 

ID_Column   |   Data
1           |   data A 1
2           |   data A 2
3           |   data A 3

TableB: 

ID_Column   |   Data
1           |   data B 1
2           |   data B 2
3           |   data B 3
```

This is what I have been trying to do

```
select C.ID_Column, data
from tableC C
      inner join tableA A
on A.ID_Column = left(C.ID_Column, 1)
      inner join tableB B
on B.ID_Column = left(C.ID_Column, 1)
```

this will return data from both tables I want to return data from table b when `ID_Column`  has `B` in the end and want to return data from `tableA` when `ID_Column`  has `A` in the end

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just out of interest - why haven't you just added a 2nd column to identify the source table in your tableC? Or even better, two columns tablea_id and tableb_id (so you'll have a cross table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `TableC` should really have at least 2 columns, one for the `id` and one to identify to which table it belongs. Anyway, this could be done this way:

```
SELECT  C.ID_Column,
        ISNULL(A.Data,B.Data) Data
FROM TableC C
LEFT JOIN TableA A
    ON LEFT(C.ID_Column,LEN(C.ID_Column)-1) = A.ID_Column
    AND RIGHT(C.ID_Column,1) = 'A'
LEFT JOIN TableB B
    ON LEFT(C.ID_Column,LEN(C.ID_Column)-1) = B.ID_Column
    AND RIGHT(C.ID_Column,1) = 'B'
```

The results are:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╗
║ D_COLUMN ║   DATA   ║
╠══════════╬══════════╣
║ 1A       ║ data A 1 ║
║ 1B       ║ data B 1 ║
║ 2A       ║ data A 2 ║
╚══════════╩══════════╝
```

[**And here is a demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/108eb/2) for you to try.

Comment: Good answer as well and I am glad you mentioned refactoring tableC.  @user3280595 you should avoid calculations in the 'column' of your predicates for performance reasons.  "Column operator value".  Have a google for SARG if you are curious why.

Answer (score 0):

You'll obviously need to tweak this a bit, but could you consider refactoring table C just a bit.  Seperate the two out and this will eliminate the calculation in the join (not a good performance tactic).

```
--Create Table A
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableA') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TableA
CREATE TABLE #TableA (ID_COLUMN INT, DATA VARCHAR(max))
INSERT INTO  #TableA(ID_COLUMN,DATA) VALUES (1,'data A 1'),(2,'data A 2'),(3,'data A 3')

--Create Table B
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableB') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TableB
CREATE TABLE #TableB (ID_COLUMN INT, DATA VARCHAR(max))
INSERT INTO #TableB (ID_COLUMN,DATA) VALUES (1,'data B 1'),(2,'data B 2'),(3,'data B 3')

--Create Table C
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableC') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TableC
CREATE TABLE #TableC (ID_COLUMN INT, ORIGIN_TABLE CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO #TableC (ID_COLUMN, ORIGIN_TABLE) VALUES (1,'A'), (1,'B'),(2,'A')

SELECT  A.ID_COLUMN, A.DATA
FROM       #TableC AS C
       INNER JOIN #TableA AS A ON (C.ID_COLUMN = A.ID_COLUMN)
WHERE   C.ORIGIN_TABLE = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT  B.ID_COLUMN, B.DATA
FROM       #TableC AS C
       INNER JOIN #TableB AS B ON (C.ID_COLUMN = B.ID_COLUMN)
WHERE   C.ORIGIN_TABLE = 'B'
```